# Prevent createElement from creating multiple identical images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am going to try and be as thorough as possible on this so stick with me.

My program takes user input entered on a form. This input goes through a range of if statements that will set variables to true, these variables that are set to true will then use createElement to create img inside predetermined divs. There will always be at least one img created, and up to 4 imgs at the most. This is all completed by a button click.

I learned createElement will continuously createElement with each button click posting the img right next to the original img and will do this infinitely or until the page is reloaded.

My solution was to create a counter that incremented each time the button was clicked. That took care of any extra createElements. Then I thought if the user first entered a large number that will create 2 separate and individual images say... image 1 and image 2 (which is desired), then if the user enters a lower number that only creates image 1, then image 2 would still be posted (unwanted). Of course a page refresh would clear the images created and avoid this.

So I'm not quite sure what to do...
Ideally when the button is pressed a second time then all old createElements would be cleared, and all new createElements would populate.

I removed the counter for the purpose of this question

poster__#'s are the called id's...

```js
const movieTime = 30;
var userTimeAvailable = 25;
const button = document.getElementById("calculate");

button.onclick = function calculateTime() {
  if (userTimeAvailable < movieTime) {
    console.log(
      "You have enough time to watch " +
      Math.round((userTimeAvailable / movieTime) * 100) +
      "% of the movie."
    );
    displayMoviePoster1 = true;
  }
  moviePosterGenerator();
}

function moviePosterGenerator() {
  if (displayMoviePoster1 === true) {
    var par = document.getElementById("poster__2");
    var theatricalMoviePoster = document.createElement("img");
    theatricalMoviePoster.src = "imgURL";
    par.appendChild(theatricalMoviePoster);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="calculate">calculate</button>

<div class="movie-poster__container" id="posters">
  <div class="movie-poster" id="poster__1"></div>
  <div class="movie-poster" id="poster__2"></div>
  <div class="movie-poster" id="poster__3"></div>
  <div class="movie-poster" id="poster__4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the button and other relevant code in a [mcve]

Comment: if you click the button again, it should remove/empty what was generated on the previuous click i guess ;)

Comment: why do you even create new elements in the first place, rather than hide/show the selected ones?  Or you can use `element.remove()` and remove the existing ones

Comment: Typo: moviePosterGenertator

Comment: `par.innerHTML =""` before adding

Comment: @mplungjan, that worked on removing the identical image, thanks.